# elasticsearch-dsl-py Sorting by Text() field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have problem with `.sort()` method. For example I have Index with Text() field:

```
FILTER = token_filter(
    'FILTER', 'edge_ngram', min_gram=3, max_gram=40)
ANALYZER = analyzer(
    'ANALYZER', tokenizer='standard', type='custom', filter=[
        'standard', 'lowercase', 'stop', 'asciifolding',FILTER])

class Article(DocType):
    title = Text(analyzer=ANALYZER)
    body = Text(analyzer='snowball')
    tags = Keyword()

search = Article.search().sort('title')
search.execute()
```

when I try to execute search query with sort I get an error:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400,
>   'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Fielddata is disabled on text
>   fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [title] in order to load
>   fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this
>   can however use significant memory.')

How can I sort by `title` field properly in this case without setting `fieldata=true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot sort on a `text` field, that is a limitation in elasticsearch. It needs to be a type `keyword`.

Unfortunately type `keyword` cannot have an analyzer, it can, however, have a `normalizer` which performs similar, albeit a bit limited, function. Essentially the difference is that you cannot specify a tokenizer since then any sorting would not make much sense (which token would you use for sorting when you have multiple?)

hope this helps

Comment: how about `String()` field? Can I sort on a `string` field?

Comment: `String` is deprecated, `String(index="not_analyzed")` was replaced by `keyword` and all other `String` instances are analogous to `text` so same restrictions apply.

Comment: Note that you don't have to choose, you can use both field types (`text` and `keyword`) by using the `fields` parameter - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html