# How can you sort documents by nested object in elastic search using go?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm new to Elasticsearch.

I have documents and each of them has a structure like this:

```
{
    "created_at": "2018-01-01 01:01:01",
    "student": {
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe"
    },
    "parent": {
        "first_name": "susan",
        "last_name": "smile"
    }
}
```

I just want to sort those documents based on `student.first_name` using `olivere/elastic` package for `go`.

This is my query at the moment:

`searchSvc = searchSvc.SortBy(elastic.NewFieldSort("student.first_name").Asc())`

and I'm getting this error:

> elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): all shards failed
>   [type=search_phase_execution_exception]

However when I tried sorting it by `created_at`, it's working.

`searchSvc = searchSvc.SortBy(elastic.NewFieldSort("created_at").Asc())`

I don't have any mapping in the index. (is this the problem?)

I tried searching for something like "Elasticsearch sort by nested object", but I always got questions that need to sort an array in the nested object.

Comment: It looks to me like `student` is an array.  I am unfamiliar with go, but is there an array access operator `[]` or similar such as you might find in C or php etc?

Comment: `student` is not an array.. it's just an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a beginner mistake.. You can't sort by text fields. I got it from here [elasticsearch-dsl-py Sorting by Text() field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220352/elasticsearch-dsl-py-sorting-by-text-field)

What you can do though, if you don't specify mappings, you can sort by the keyword property of the field.

`searchSvc = searchSvc.SortBy(elastic.NewFieldSort("student.first_name.keyword").Asc())`

And it works!

Comment: The keyword field needs to be set in the mapping of the field (unless its a dynamic text field in which elastic produces a mapping with 'keyword' field and limits it to 256 chars , or something like that). The reason you cannot sort on a simple text field without a keyword-field or a fielddata=true , is because it is not a doc_value type of field, and its indexed values are produced from the standard text analyzer (like array with multiple words) rather than a single value.

Comment: @NiritLevi yes! thanks so much! I need to dive deeper in to Elasticsearch's documentation!